Why does tableRow.get() return undefined in p5.js?
I'm trying to practice data table with geolocation. But p5 can't load data from tableRow.get(), as I printed the lat and lon, it says undefined. What's the problem?
let Soho;
let table;
let lat, lon, xgeo, ygeo;

let mapGeoLeft = -0.1424;
let mapGeoRight = -0.131;
let mapGeoTop = 51.5164;
let mapGeoBottom = 51.5093;

function preload() {
  soho = loadImage("cholera.png");
  table = loadTable("cholera.csv");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(soho);
}

function draw() {
  for (let r = 0; r < table.getRowCount(); r++) {
    let tableRow = table.rows[r];
    lat = tableRow.get("lat");
    lon = tableRow.get("lon");

    xgeo = map(lon, mapGeoLeft, mapGeoRight, 0, width);
    ygeo = map(lat, mapGeoTop, mapGeoBottom, 0, height);

    fill(255, 0, 0);
    strokeWeight(0.5);
    circle(xgeo, ygeo, 5);
  }
  print(lat);
  noLoop();
}

here is the first few lines of data from the table:
count,lon,lat
3,-0.13793,51.513418
2,-0.137883,51.513361
1,-0.137853,51.513317
1,-0.137812,51.513262
4,-0.137767,51.513204
2,-0.137537,51.513184


Aside: let Soho; should be let soho;

What do you see if you do console.log(tableRow)?

I see an error message...

You can use the third argument to tell the table parser that there's a header:
loadTable("cholera.csv", "csv", "header");

The rest of your code should work without modification after this change. See the docs for loadTable.

BTW, always use const or let rather than creating global variables, so lat = tableRow.get("lat"); should be const lat = tableRow.get("lat");, and so on.
Also use let soho rather than let Soho.
These typos and declaration scoping issues can lead to subtle bugs.

and may I ask why need const?

You don't need it, but it's a good idea. Most importantly, const scopes the variable to the block so it's not a global, where it can easily clash with something else and lead to bugs. Secondly, you can't reassign it, meaning you have a guarantee that the value will never change if it's a primitive, and that it's always the same object if it's an object. Finally, you communicate to the reader that it'll never change, so when you do use let, you're saying "I will reassign this", which makes the code easier to read--you can see which variables change and which don't at a glance.

Generally, you don't want to modify or reassign variables if you can help it. More mutations/reassignments means more complexity, more state to keep in your head, and more chance of bugs. Some programming languages like Haskell completely forbid modifying data. Extreme, but the extent to which you can follow this rule of thumb in JS, the more bugs you'll avoid. See also someone answers.

got it, very specific. thanks a lot.
